# WHich fields are changed by Salesforce internally when a lead is converted?

Tags: lead-conversion

When we convert a lead to a account which fields are changed internally by Salesforce for example:

Lead Status is changed to Closed Converted, isConverted is changed  are there any other fields which Salesforce internally changes on lead Conversion

Answer (score 1):

The following fields are updated

- ConvertedAccountId
- ConvertedContactId
- ConvertedDate
- ConvertedOpportunityId

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm